# WMS 1.3.0 from ArcGIS Server not work in GeoExt (OpenGeo Suite 3.0.2)

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, geoext

I used geoext sample app as in the example. added a new source and layers. but does not work: warn message "Non-existing source 'rs' referenced in layer config".

but the response from the server comes (I see it in Firebug)!
server ArcGIS Server and WMS version 1.3.0
http://maps.rosreestr.ru/ArcGIS/services/CadastreNew/CadastreWMS/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

I'm just starting to learn javascript

```
 /**
 * Add all your dependencies here.
 *
 * @require widgets/Viewer.js
 * @require plugins/LayerTree.js
 * @require plugins/OLSource.js
 * @require plugins/OSMSource.js
 * @require plugins/WMSCSource.js
 * @require plugins/WMSSource.js // for my source
 * @require plugins/BingSource.js
 * @require plugins/GoogleSource.js  
 * @require plugins/ZoomToExtent.js
 * @require plugins/NavigationHistory.js
 * @require plugins/Zoom.js
 * @require plugins/AddLayers.js
 * @require plugins/RemoveLayer.js
 * @require RowExpander.js
 * @require plugins/WMSGetFeatureInfo.js
 * @require plugins/FeatureManager.js
 * @require plugins/FeatureEditor.js
 * @require plugins/FeatureGrid.js
 * @require plugins/DrawBox.js
 * @require plugins/BoxInfo.js
 */

var app = new gxp.Viewer({
    portalConfig: {
        layout: "border",
        region: "center",

        // by configuring items here, we don't need to configure portalItems
        // and save a wrapping container
        items: [{
            id: "centerpanel",
            xtype: "panel",
            layout: "fit",
            region: "center",
            border: false,
            items: ["mymap"]
        }, {
            id: "westpanel",
            xtype: "container",
            layout: "fit",
            region: "west",
            width: 200
        },{
            id: "south",
            xtype: "container",
            layout: "fit",
            region: "south",
            border: false,
            height: 200
        }, {
            id: "southpanel",
            xtype: "container",
            layout: "fit",
            region: "south",
            height: 100
        }
        ],
        bbar: {id: "mybbar"}
    },

    // configuration of all tool plugins for this application
    tools: [{
        ptype: "gxp_layertree",
        outputConfig: {
            id: "tree",
            border: true,
            tbar: [] // we will add buttons to "tree.bbar" later
        },
        outputTarget: "westpanel"
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_addlayers",
        actionTarget: "tree.tbar"
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_removelayer",
        actionTarget: ["tree.tbar", "tree.contextMenu"]
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_zoomtoextent",
        actionTarget: "map.tbar"
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_zoom",
        actionTarget: "map.tbar"
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_navigationhistory",
        actionTarget: "map.tbar"
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_wmsgetfeatureinfo",
        featureManager: "states_manager",
        outputConfig: {
            width: 700
        },
        actionTarget: {
            target: "map.tbar",
            index: 1
        }
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_featuremanager",
        id: "states_manager",
        paging: false,
        autoLoadFeatures: true,
        layer: {
            source: "local",
            name: "geo:fence"
        }
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_featureeditor",
        featureManager: "states_manager",
        autoLoadFeature: true
    }, /*{
        ptype: "gxp_featuregrid",
        featureManager: "states_manager",
        outputConfig: {
            loadMask: true
        },
        outputTarget: "south"
    },*/ {
        ptype: "myapp_drawbox",
        id: "drawbox",
        actionTarget: "map.tbar"
    }, {
        ptype: "myapp_boxinfo",
        boxTool: "drawbox",
        outputTarget: "southpanel"
    }
    ],

    // layer sources
    sources: {
        local: {
            ptype: "gxp_wmscsource",
            url: "/geoserver/wms",
            version: "1.1.1"
        },
        osm: {
            ptype: "gxp_osmsource"
        },
        rs: {
            ptype: "gxp_wmssource",
            url: "http://maps.rosreestr.ru/ArcGIS/services/CadastreNew/CadastreWMS/MapServer/WMSServer"
            ,transparent: true,
            format: "png",
            version: "1.3.0"
        },
        bing: {
            ptype: "gxp_bingsource"
        },
        google: {
            ptype: "gxp_googlesource"
        }
    },

    // map and layers
    map: {
        id: "mymap", // id needed to reference map in portalConfig above
        title: "Map",
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        center: [4187314.9432233, 7447312.6747233],
        zoom: 17,
        layers: [{
            source: "osm",
            name: "mapnik",
            group: "background"
        }, {
            source: "bing",
            name: "Aerial",
            title: "Bing Map",
            group: "background"
        }, { 
            source: "google",
            name: "SATELLITE",
            group: "background"
        }, { 
            source: "rs",
            name: "22,21,20,19,18,16,15,14,13,11,10,9,7,6,4,3,2,1",
            //,group: "background",
            visibility: true    
        }, {
            source: "local",
            name: "geo:roadcover",
            selected: true,
            visibility: true
        }, {
            source: "local",
            name: "geo:bridge_polygon",
            visibility: true    
        }, {
            source: "local",
            name: "geo:cadastre_s",
            visibility: true
        }, {
            source: "local",
            name: "geo:fence",
            visibility: false
        }, {
            source: "local",
            name: "geo:curbs",
            visibility: false
        }, {
            source: "local",
            name: "geo:layout_polygon",
            visibility: false
        }, {
            source: "local",
            name: "geo:RoadInternodalSegment",
            visibility: true
        }
        ],
        items: [{
            xtype: "gx_zoomslider",
            vertical: true,
            height: 100
        }]
    }

   });
```

this screenshot from Firebug
http://gis-lab.info/forum/download/file.php?id=6569&sid=2c5226b95b2cb52e97280be1d6039655

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

understood! external WMS added through plugins/OLSource.js
use plugins/WMSSource.js is possible only for my data (Geoserver)

```
{
        source: "ol",
        type: "OpenLayers.Layer.WMS",
        args: ["Информация Росреестра", "http://maps.rosreestr.ru/ArcGIS/services/CadastreNew/CadastreWMS/MapServer/WMSServer",
            {transparent: 'true', layers: "22,21,20,19,18,16,15,14,13,11,10,9,7,6,4,3,2,1", format: 'png24'}],
        selected: true,
        visibility: true
    }
```